# Python nested if statements with list comprehension

Tags: python, nested, list-comprehension

How can you nest multiple ifs while you have list comprehension?

I have this function:

```
@click.command 
@click.option(--a) 
@click.option(--b) 
def func1(a,b): 
  for x in list1:
    if any([a, b]):
      if any(x==a, x==b]):
        print ('x')
    else:
      print ('x')
```

As you can see example function takes optional parameters.
So if a or b is passed to func1 only x that matches a or b will be printed.
If no parameters are passed all elements of list1 will be printed.

How can i do this with list comprehension with nested if else statements?

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: The list brackets in `if any(...` do not match...

Comment: It will also print `'x'`, not `x`...

Comment: Not the best example, if it is only about printing out some results then I would **not** mix that up with list comprehension.

Comment: don't use list comprehensions only for side effects.

Comment: The example given doesn't need nested ifs, as you do not have to check any([a, b]) because you are not accessing any of their methods or attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you example is the good one in which you can use `multiple ifs`within `list comprehension`.

Otherwise, you can look at this example and modify it to fill your needs:

I suppose, i have a `list of lists` called `a` like this one:

```
a = [[1, 2, 0], [5, 6, 0], [0, 3, 5]]
```

And i want to find if each element of each sublist is `odd`, `even` or `zero` then return another list of lists with the new informations about my default list of lists.

So, using `list comprehension` and `multiple ifs`, i can do something like this:

```
final = [["odd" if (k %2 != 0 and k != 0) else "even" if (k%2 == 0 and k!=0) else "zero" for k in j] for j in a ]

print(final)
```

Output:

```
>>> [['odd', 'even', 'zero'], ['odd', 'even', 'zero'], ['zero', 'odd', 'odd']]
```